# Can you have Window creation code within a library?

Tags: windows

I'm making a library that will act as a graphics aid, and one of the things I wanted to add was it's own Window creation.

I've seen how people use the default windows code in a Windows application, but that would only work in that project not the library.

Is it possible to add in window creation code into a library and have it behave in such a way like :

```
windowClass instance = libraryCreateWindow(blah,blah);
instance.showWindow();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. There is effectively no difference in creating a window from a library than from the main executable.

Windows belong to a process and are associated with a thread, it doesn't matter where in the code or in what module the window is created. I'm not sure what you're basing the statement "that would only work in that project not the library" on.

You didn't specify whether you were talking about a dynamic or static library, a C++ class library, or even a C#/.NET library, and the implementation details obviously differ depending on language and framework, but the answer should still be yes for any of the above.

Comment: This is a c++ static library. Would I still have to add the WinApi LRESULT CALLBACK functions in order to get the HINSTANCE of a window? Adding to that question, would I also have to add the MessageBox functionality that exists the window and all that, or can I write up my own one.